# Chart.js will not show up second line

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a question about chart.js. I created a line chart with two lines. One line for the high values and one line for the lower values.

Everything works fine, but the low red line won't appear in the diagram. Is there anything i have forgotten?

Thank you for your help!

```js
var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['16:30', '17:30', '18:30', '19:30', '20:30'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'High',
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
      borderColor: 'blue',
      data: [10.43, 10.42, 10.44, 10.43, 10.40],
      fill: false,
    }, {
      label: 'low',
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      borderColor: 'red',
      data: [
        [8.43, 8.5, 8.39, 8.38, 8.38],
      ],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Test'
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false,
    },
    hover: {
      mode: 'nearest',
      intersect: true
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Time'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Value'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
};
var ctx = $('#dia');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>


<canvas id="dia"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second dataset data array is double wrapped:

```
data: [
        [8.43, 8.5, 8.39, 8.38, 8.38],
      ],
```

Removing the second set of brackets generates the graph correctly.

```js
var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['16:30', '17:30', '18:30', '19:30', '20:30'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'High',
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
      borderColor: 'blue',
      data: [10.43, 10.42, 10.44, 10.43, 10.40],
      fill: false,
    }, {
      label: 'low',
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      borderColor: 'red',
      data: [8.43, 8.5, 8.39, 8.38, 8.38], // ****THIS IS WHERE THE UPDATE IS****
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Test'
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false,
    },
    hover: {
      mode: 'nearest',
      intersect: true
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Time'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Value'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
};
var ctx = $('#dia');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>


<canvas id="dia"></canvas>
```

Comment: Is it possible to diplay the diagram without the blue label. I will only see the blue line, not the blue label. But I need the red label

Comment: @InFlames82 good question! I would suggest asking a new question on this site